# Java throwing Error and catching NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

This is something that doesn't make sense to me.

First example:

EXAMPLE 1 (GOOD):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            Exception e = null;
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Everything is fine with ths code - exception is thrown and catched.

EXAMPLE 2 (BAD):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
        Exception e = null;
        throw e;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}
```

This will not compile because catch block can't catch `NullPointerException` which is subclass of `Exception`. It doesn't know what kind of exception will be thrown.

```
java.lang.Object
    java.lang.Throwable
        java.lang.Exception  --> Thrown
            java.lang.RuntimeException
                java.lang.NullPointerException  --> Cannot catch like this
```

So let's change exception to `NullPointerException`:

EXAMPLE 3 (GOOD)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        NullPointerException e = null;
        throw e;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
```

Simple and logical, But here comes something really weird:

EXAMPLE 4 (GOOD) - no idea why ?:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Error e = null;
        throw e;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
```

If I throw an `Error`, how can I catch `NullPointerException`? It makes no sense.

There is:

Throwable: Error, Exception

Both `Error` and `Exception` are sub-classes of `Throwable`, but `NullPoinTerException` has nothing to with `Error`, it's an `Exception`, not `Error`.

Comment: None of these examples are good.   Where did you get them?

Comment: Are you sure that `catch (NullPointerException e)` *catches* the `Error`?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of my question :)

Comment: [JLS 14.18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18): "If evaluation of the Expression completes normally, producing a `null` value, then an instance `V'` of class `NullPointerException` is created and thrown instead of `null`. The throw statement then completes abruptly, the reason being a throw with value `V'`. "

Comment: Also, your description of example 2 is incorrect. The compiler complains because you throw an unchecked `Exception` and don't catch it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP is describing example 2, containing the apparent paradox, incorrectly.

Answer (score 8):

You are attempting to throw a null object, which fails, and causes a `NullPointerException` to be thrown instead.

You should throw an exception with `throw new Exception ();`

Just to clarify. In case you were asking why your second example doesn't compile, while the fourth example does :

Error and its sub-classes are unchecked exceptions, which doesn't have to be caught or declared in a `throws` clause.

> **The unchecked exception classes** are the run-time exception classes **and the error classes**.

([JLS 11.1.1.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html))

That's why you can throw an `Error` and catch an `Exception`, and the code will compile.

On the other hand, in your second example, you are trying to throw a checked exception (`Exception`) and catch a `NullPointerException`, which is not a super-class of `Exception`. That's why the code won't compile unless you catch `Exception` or declare that your main method `throws Exception`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but please check the last example.

Comment: The point is that *the `throw` command itself* is throwing the exception because you're trying to `throw null`.

Comment: So it doesn't matter that I'm throwing Error instead of exception, exception is thrown ?

Comment: @RichardK Your last example makes no difference. You are still throwing a null object, hence the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You're *not* throwing `Error`. You're throwing a `NullPointerException` that is created implicitly.

Comment: This answer is correct, however it can be difficult to grasp the difference between throwing a `NullPointerException e` and throwing a NullPointerException for a beginner :)

Comment: @RichardK You are not throwing an Error. Your attempt to throw an Error fails, and instead `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Comment: So why it doesn't work when I'm trying to throw Exception ? - EXAMPLE 2 ?

Comment: @RichardK You are trying to throw a null object in all 4 examples. Therefore the result is the same in all of them. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: Example 2:  Exception e = null; throw e; - not compiling
Example 4:  Error e = null; throw e; - compiling and ok

Comment: @RichardK What's your point? You're getting a compile-time error there because you throw a checked exception and don't catch it or specify it in a `throws` clause.

Comment: If example 4 is ok example 2 should also be ok, but it's not - that's my point.

Comment: @RichardK because an Error doesn't require a try - catch, but Exception does

Answer (score 1):

The are two things to notice.

First, a `NullPointerException` is thrown because you are throwing a `null` object. This has nothing to do with the declared type of the exception you were trying to throw.

Second, since subclasses of `Error` are *unchecked exceptions*, the compiler does not complain that a catch block for `Error` is missing. Your second example didn't compile, because it is not the case that all subclasses of `Exception` are unchecked exceptions. Thus when the compiler encountered a `throw e` statement where the declared type of `e` was `Exception`, it required a catch block for `Exception`.